# What faction is Tori?

Tags: character-motivation, divergent

In [Divergent](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/), there are 5 factions.

- Abnegation (the selfless)
- Amity (the peaceful)
- Candor (the honest)
- Dauntless (the brave) and
- Erudite (the intelligent)

Which faction does Tori (who administers the test to Beatrice & side-lines as a tattoo artist) belong to?

[image]
<sub>Tori preparing to administer the faction test to Beatrice</sub>

I figure she:

- Cannot be Candor, given she encourages Beatrice to lie about the result of her test.
- Cannot be Abnegation, given the styled hair and tattoo.
- Dresses like a dauntless (at least the color), but it seems strange a dauntless would be running these tests.
- Could be Amity, given her concern over a girl she just met, but they were largely shown as working in the fields.
- Erudite?  If so, she might have even known what they were plotting (which could help explain her actions).
- Factionless?  She seemed to be dressed a lot better than the factionless, and the impression was that they were unemployed and dependent on hand outs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Tori is Dauntless](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=what+faction+is+Tori). The book explains Tori's reasons to volunteer for this annual duty. When it's not Testing Day, she's the tattoo artist.

Most of the test administrators are Abnegation, but Abnegation teens are tested by members of other factions, to avoid bias & social pressure.

Comment: My bad!  I checked the other divergent questions on SO, looked at the IMDb & main wikipedia page, but forgot to search the exact question.  :-P  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. :)